# how to make google map markers refresh every 5 seconds without reloading the whole map

Tags: javascript

for the past couple of hours I have been trying to get only the markers to reload but i can only make the whole map reload

i have tried putting some bindmarkers function but still to no avail

```
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.1899, -88.534721),
      zoom: 8
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file

      downloadUrl('xml1.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = id
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[id] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the reload? Do you want it to redraw?

Comment: i just need it to update the markers it currently has every 5 seconds its getting the latitude and longitude from mysql database and those values are always going to be changing

Comment: This should do `setInterval( ()=> {...update here...}, 5000);`

Comment: yes i did have it but it reloads the entire map while i just want it to reload only the markers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload Markers on Google's Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773651/reload-markers-on-googles-maps-api)

Comment: i will give that one a try and see how it goes